# unable to show AJAX loader while image is being loaded completely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a image slider and here is my code so far:

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller("imageController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  var imageArray = [  // dynamic array
    'http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/thumbnails/random_comics.png',
    'http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30200000/-random-30240825-200-200.gif',
    'https://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/059_QTRandom/Preview/Preview.png'
  ];

  var index = 0;  // so as to have the first image displayed when the page is loaded

  $scope.showAjaxLoader = true;  // show

  $scope.url = imageArray[index];

  $scope.showAjaxLoader = false;  // hide

  if(imageArray.length > 0){
    $scope.showNext = true;
  }

  $scope.getPrev = function(){
    $scope.showAjaxLoader = true;  // show
    
    index--;
    $scope.url = imageArray[index];
    if(index === 0){
      $scope.showPrev = false;
    }
    $scope.showNext = true;
    
    $scope.showAjaxLoader = false;  // hide
  };

  $scope.getNext = function(){
    $scope.showAjaxLoader = true;  // show
    
    index++;
    $scope.url = imageArray[index];
    if(index === imageArray.length-1){
      $scope.showNext = false;
    }
    $scope.showPrev = true;
    
    $scope.showAjaxLoader = false;  // hide
  };
}]);
```

```css
img{
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(50% - 17px);
    font-size: 25px;
}

#previous{
    left: 0px;
}

#next{
    right: 0px;
}

/* AJAX loader */

#circularG{
 position:relative;
 width:58px;
 height:58px;
 margin: auto;
}

.circularG{
 position:absolute;
 background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
 width:14px;
 height:14px;
 border-radius:9px;
  -o-border-radius:9px;
  -ms-border-radius:9px;
  -webkit-border-radius:9px;
  -moz-border-radius:9px;
 animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -o-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -ms-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -webkit-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -moz-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
 animation-duration:1.1s;
  -o-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -ms-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1.1s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-direction:normal;
  -o-animation-direction:normal;
  -ms-animation-direction:normal;
  -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
  -moz-animation-direction:normal;
}

#circularG_1{
 left:0;
 top:23px;
 animation-delay:0.41s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.41s;
}

#circularG_2{
 left:6px;
 top:6px;
 animation-delay:0.55s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.55s;
}

#circularG_3{
 top:0;
 left:23px;
 animation-delay:0.69s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.69s;
}

#circularG_4{
 right:6px;
 top:6px;
 animation-delay:0.83s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.83s;
}

#circularG_5{
 right:0;
 top:23px;
 animation-delay:0.97s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.97s;
}

#circularG_6{
 right:6px;
 bottom:6px;
 animation-delay:1.1s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.1s;
}

#circularG_7{
 left:23px;
 bottom:0;
 animation-delay:1.24s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.24s;
}

#circularG_8{
 left:6px;
 bottom:6px;
 animation-delay:1.38s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.38s;
}



@keyframes bounce_circularG{
 0%{
  transform:scale(1);
 }

 100%{
  transform:scale(.3);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_circularG{
 0%{
  -o-transform:scale(1);
 }

 100%{
  -o-transform:scale(.3);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG{
 0%{
  -ms-transform:scale(1);
 }

 100%{
  -ms-transform:scale(.3);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG{
 0%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
 }

 100%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_circularG{
 0%{
  -moz-transform:scale(1);
 }

 100%{
  -moz-transform:scale(.3);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="imageController">

    <!-- AJAX loader -->
    <div id="circularG" ng-show='showAjaxLoader'>
      <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next/Previous buttons -->
    <button id='previous' ng-click='getPrev()' ng-init='showPrev=false' ng-show='showPrev'>Prev</button>
    <button id='next' ng-click='getNext()' ng-show='showNext'>Next</button>

    <!-- image -->
    <img src={{url}} />

  </div>
</body>
```

It works fine, except the fact that the AJAX loader is not displayed while the other image is being loaded completely. The problem is that it gets hidden immediately when I set the `ng-show` to `false`.

How do I make it to work so that it is shown while the image is being fetched or completely loaded on the webpage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/angularjs-image-onload-event doesnt work?

Comment: Check whether this link is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290320/show-a-loading-screen-as-background-images-load-in-ng-repeat

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I tried that, it just works on the first load: https://jsfiddle.net/qbge5qse/24/ Am I missing anything?

Comment: I guess you need to add a watch on "url" and check if the image is loaded completely or not, inside it.

Comment: @SaiGiridhar How to check if the image is loaded completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an image url changes, a new javascript image object is created, and the image onload event is used to cancel the ajax loader.

Note that after an image was loaded, it is cached by the browser, so the ajax loader will usually appear once for every image. To see the ajax loader again, you'll have to clean the cache.

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller("imageController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  var imageArray = [  // dynamic array
    'http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/thumbnails/random_comics.png',
    'http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30200000/-random-30240825-200-200.gif',
    'https://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/059_QTRandom/Preview/Preview.png'
  ];

  var index = 0; // so as to have the first image displayed when the page is loaded

  showImage(imageArray[index]);

  function showImage(url) {
    $scope.showAjaxLoader = true; // show

    var img = new Image(); // create a new image

    img.onload = function () { // create an image onload event handler
      $scope.$apply(function () { // don't forget to apply as the event is out of angular digest cycle
        $scope.showAjaxLoader = false; // hide when image is loaded
      });

    };
    $scope.url = url;
    img.src = url; // assign url to image

  }

  if (imageArray.length > 0) {
    $scope.showNext = true;
  }

  $scope.getPrev = function () {
    index--;
    showImage(imageArray[index]);
    if (index === 0) {
      $scope.showPrev = false;
    }
    $scope.showNext = true;
  };

  $scope.getNext = function () {
    index++;
    showImage(imageArray[index]);
    if (index === imageArray.length - 1) {
      $scope.showNext = false;
    }
    $scope.showPrev = true;

  };
}
                               ]);
```

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
}

button{
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 17px);
  font-size: 25px;
}

#previous{
  left: 0px;
}

#next{
  right: 0px;
}

/* AJAX loader */

#circularG{
  position: fixed;
  width:58px;
  height:58px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 100px;
  left: calc(50% - 29px);
}

.circularG{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  width:14px;
  height:14px;
  border-radius:9px;
  -o-border-radius:9px;
  -ms-border-radius:9px;
  -webkit-border-radius:9px;
  -moz-border-radius:9px;
  animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -o-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -ms-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -webkit-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  -moz-animation-name:bounce_circularG;
  animation-duration:1.1s;
  -o-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -ms-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1.1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:normal;
  -o-animation-direction:normal;
  -ms-animation-direction:normal;
  -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
  -moz-animation-direction:normal;
}

#circularG_1{
  left:0;
  top:23px;
  animation-delay:0.41s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.41s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.41s;
}

#circularG_2{
  left:6px;
  top:6px;
  animation-delay:0.55s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.55s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.55s;
}

#circularG_3{
  top:0;
  left:23px;
  animation-delay:0.69s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.69s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.69s;
}

#circularG_4{
  right:6px;
  top:6px;
  animation-delay:0.83s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.83s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.83s;
}

#circularG_5{
  right:0;
  top:23px;
  animation-delay:0.97s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.97s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.97s;
}

#circularG_6{
  right:6px;
  bottom:6px;
  animation-delay:1.1s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.1s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.1s;
}

#circularG_7{
  left:23px;
  bottom:0;
  animation-delay:1.24s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.24s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.24s;
}

#circularG_8{
  left:6px;
  bottom:6px;
  animation-delay:1.38s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.38s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.38s;
}



@keyframes bounce_circularG{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1);
  }

  100%{
    transform:scale(.3);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_circularG{
  0%{
    -o-transform:scale(1);
  }

  100%{
    -o-transform:scale(.3);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_circularG{
  0%{
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
  }

  100%{
    -ms-transform:scale(.3);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_circularG{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  }

  100%{
    -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_circularG{
  0%{
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
  }

  100%{
    -moz-transform:scale(.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="imageController">

    <!-- AJAX loader -->
    <div id="circularG" ng-show='showAjaxLoader'>
      <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG"></div>
      <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next/Previous buttons -->
    <button id='previous' ng-click='getPrev()' ng-init='showPrev=false' ng-show='showPrev'>Prev</button>
    <button id='next' ng-click='getNext()' ng-show='showNext'>Next</button>

    <!-- image -->
    <img src={{url}} />

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the alternate way using angular directive.

https://jsfiddle.net/8drLy2bp/1/

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .directive('orientable', function () {       
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {   
           $scope.$watch("url", function(newValue){
            element.bind("load" , function(e){ 

                $scope.$apply(function(){
                   $scope.showAjaxLoader = false;
                });
            });
          });
        }
    }
    });
```